# Function that filters away reoccuring groups of values in an array is not working

Tags: javascript

I have an array with values in it. I'm trying to check if two following values that are being pushed into the array already exists in that order.

Here's the code:

```js
let items = [];
let x = 0;
let y = 0;
let xc = [0, 10, 15, 20];
let yc = [0, 10, 15, 20];

function fillArray() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    x = xc[Math.floor(Math.random() * xc.length)];
    y = yc[Math.floor(Math.random() * yc.length)];
    while (checkIfGroupExists(items, [x, y])) {
      console.log(`sequence ${x},${y} already exists.`);
      x = xc[Math.floor(Math.random() * xc.length)];
      y = yc[Math.floor(Math.random() * yc.length)];
    }
    items.push(x, y);
  }
}

function checkIfGroupExists(arr, sequence) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return false;
  }

  const first = sequence[0];
  let index = arr.indexOf(first, 0);

  while (index > -1) {
    if (sequence.every((v, i) => arr[index + i] === v)) {
      return true;
    }

    index = arr.indexOf(first, index);
    if (index == -1) {
      return false;
    }
    index++;
  }

  return false;
}


console.log(items);
```

Now I get the message "Sequence x,y already exists." and it looks like whenever that message is being logged, the sequence does not get pushed. However, at some of the loops the groups are not being found in the array and a sequence that already exists is pushed.

Results example:

```
[
  15, //(x)
  10, //(y)
  0,  //(x)
  0,  //(y)
  20, //(x)
  10, //(y)
  20, //(x) <-- 
  15, //(y) <-- 
  20, //(x)
  0,  //(y)
  10, //(x)
  15, //(y)
  20, //(x)
  0,  //(y)
  0,  //(x)
  15, //(y)
  20, //(x) <--
  15, //(y) <-- 
  20, //(x)
  20  //(y)
]
```

Here the group 20,15 is pushed into the array twice. The reoccurring 0,0 doesn't matter since they are not reoccuring in the same "group", eg. x=0 followed by y=0, but the 20,15-group does. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way simpler way to check for a sequence of two elements, unless I'm missing something. I'm assuming that x needs to be an even index, and y odd.

```js
function checkIfGroupExists(arr, sequence) {
  for (let i = 0; i<arr.length-1; i+=2)
    if (arr[i] === sequence[0] && arr[i+1] === sequence[1]) return true;
  return false;
}

const arr = [
  15, 
  10, 
  0,  
  0,  
  20, 
  10, 
  20, 
  15, 
  20, 
  0,  
  10, 
  15, 
  20, 
  0,   
]

console.log(checkIfGroupExists(arr, [20,15]))
```

Note your function fails this test, I can't tell exactly what you did wrong because I can't really follow the logic to be honest.

Comment: that works. I can't believe I've tried all that code and it works with a single line, haha. The idea is to have an x-coordinate and an y-coordinate. Index i holds the x-coordinate while index i+1 holds the y-coordinate. And if the x and y exists in the array with the same values in the same order, then I want to generate new numbers. But what you suggested works. Thankk you very much! I'm new to JS, so I can understand if my code doesn't make sense.

Comment: @leo No problem, but consider a two dimensional array for x,y coords. like: `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`. Much easier to deal with.